# Postgres: Update field and round it

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, rounding

I have huge table where occasionally one column got not rounded values,
e.g. 16345.462500 instead of 16345.460000

I'm not that good in postgres - **maybe it's possible to update table rounding those values**?

I can't change field type, because some rows (cryptocurrencies) can contain not rounded numbers.

Easiest thing I can think about is PHP script to manually update all fields.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `round` function to round to N decimal places - in your case, 2:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET    mycolumn = ROUND(mycolumn, 2)
```